# Reading wav files - Native int16 values not doubles

Tags: python, c++, audio

Is it possible to extract the same values as Python does in their library?

For example, I'm using C++ and have managed to extract values of type double from a .wav file, however, when working in Python the values are in `int16` format. Here is what I have so far:

```
 uint16_t c;
 for(unsigned i=0; (i < size); i++)
 {
    c = (unsigned)(data[i]);
    rawSignal.push_back(c);
 }
```

This does not work, because when reading the wav file in using Python:

```
w = wave.open(wavefile,"rb")
p = w.getparams()
s = w.readframes(p[3])
w.close()
sd = np.fromstring(s, np.int16)
```

I get the following graph displayed:

[image]

However using the method above, I get the following:

[image]

NOTE: When using double values, it displays correctly. So is there an effective way to convert the double into the 'uint16_t' format?

Comment: little endian/big endian?

Comment: 16-bit PCM data is signed, try using `int16_t` instead of `uint16_t`.

Comment: are you sure, that the waveformat is 16bit pcm?

Comment: Although there are other possible encodings, most wav files are little-endian, signed 16-bit. 8-bit wav files are unsigned, but they are the frustrating exception, not the rule.

Comment: @BjornRoche Any possible ideas?